# Download file without extension with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna download some files through js.

The following code works fine when the file has an extension *ie. http://example.com/img.jpg*, but when it doesn't *ie. http://example.com/img* it just redirects me to a blank page with the file, as a normal link does.

```
function downloadURI(uri) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

How do I get over this issue, and make the browser to download?

Comment: that'd depend on what the server you're hidding does with that url....`/img` and `/img.jpg` are generally treated as two entirely different urls. one's an attempt to access a file/directory whose name is simply `img`, and the other is hitting a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply tell your browser that it's a download:

```
function downloadURI(uri) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = uri;
  link.download = 'download';
  link.click();

}

downloadURI('test')
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the folder where you want it to be downloaded too?

Comment: You mean the folder on the client's pc? No that's not possible

Comment: Thanks! :) I'm trying to backup photos before a social network shut downs forever, and wanted to save the date, maybe add it to filename would be the best choice?

Comment: for example, yes. @Dane411

Comment: I was thinking... Is there a way to edit the metadata of the image you're about to download?